# Windows 10: Pip install error: Command errored out with exit status 1

Tags: python, windows, pip

Whenever I try to use pip install I get this:

```
pip install matplotlib
Collecting matplotlib
  Using cached matplotlib-3.3.2.tar.gz (37.9 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
```

Followed by a large load of error text ending in:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

How can I sort this? Both python and pip work fine other than this.
I have tested that bit is actually downloaded (e.g. running `pip`) and that works

For full error text see below.

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\users\moris\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Moris\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-32tukx36\\matplotlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Moris\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-32tukx36\\matplotlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Moris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-dv8fnr1y'
     cwd: C:\Users\Moris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-32tukx36\matplotlib\
Complete output (248 lines):
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\moris\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\moris\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\Moris\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpthg6lsy2'
         cwd: C:\Users\Moris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-pwhy6ir8\numpy
    Complete output (200 lines):
    Running from numpy source directory.
    setup.py:470: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
      run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
    Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pxd.in
    Processing numpy/random\bit_generator.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\mtrand.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pyx.in
    Processing numpy/random\_common.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_generator.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_mt19937.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_pcg64.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_philox.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_sfc64.pyx
    Cythonizing sources
    blas_opt_info:
    blas_mkl_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\users\\moris\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\moris\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blis_info:
      libraries blis not found in ['c:\\users\\moris\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\moris\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\moris\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\moris\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
    get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
    customize GnuFCompiler
    Could not locate executable g77
    Could not locate executable f77
    customize IntelVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable ifort
    Could not locate executable ifl
    customize AbsoftFCompiler
    Could not locate executable f90
    customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable DF
    customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable efl
    customize Gnu95FCompiler
    Could not locate executable gfortran
    Could not locate executable f95
    customize G95FCompiler
    Could not locate executable g95
    customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
    customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
    Could not locate executable efort
    Could not locate executable efc
    customize PGroupFlangCompiler
    Could not locate executable flang
    don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries tatlas not found in ['c:\\users\\moris\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\moris\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_info:
      libraries satlas not found in ['c:\\users\\moris\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\moris\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['c:\\users\\moris\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\moris\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['c:\\users\\moris\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\moris\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    accelerate_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\Moris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-pwhy6ir8\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
        Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
        Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
        A better performance should be easily gained by switching
        Blas library.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
    blas_info:
      libraries blas not found in ['c:\\users\\moris\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\moris\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\Moris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-pwhy6ir8\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
        the BLAS environment variable.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
    blas_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\Moris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-pwhy6ir8\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
        the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
      NOT AVAILABLE

    non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
    lapack_opt_info:
    lapack_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\users\\moris\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\moris\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_lapack_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\moris\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\moris\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_clapack_info:
      libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['c:\\users\\moris\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\moris\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    flame_info:
      libraries flame not found in ['c:\\users\\moris\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\moris\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\moris\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\users\moris\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\moris\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\users\moris\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_info:
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\moris\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\users\moris\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\moris\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\users\moris\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\moris\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\users\moris\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\moris\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\users\moris\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\moris\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in c:\users\moris\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\moris\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in c:\users\moris\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_info:
      libraries lapack not found in ['c:\\users\\moris\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\moris\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\Moris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-pwhy6ir8\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1748: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\Moris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-pwhy6ir8\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1748: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
      NOT AVAILABLE

    numpy_linalg_lapack_lite:
      FOUND:
        language = c
        define_macros = [('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_')]

    c:\users\moris\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running dist_info
    running build_src
    build_src
    building py_modules sources
    creating build
    creating build\src.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\src.win-amd64-3.9\numpy
    creating build\src.win-amd64-3.9\numpy\distutils
    building library "npymath" sources
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\moris\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\moris\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\Moris\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpthg6lsy2' Check the logs for full command output.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\moris\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py", line 126, in fetch_build_egg
    subprocess.check_call(cmd)
  File "c:\users\moris\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 373, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['c:\\users\\moris\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', 'C:\\Users\\Moris\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp4qum52k3', '--quiet', 'numpy>=1.15']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Moris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-32tukx36\matplotlib\setup.py", line 242, in <module>
    setup(  # Finally, pass this all along to distutils to do the heavy lifting.
  File "c:\users\moris\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 152, in setup
    _install_setup_requires(attrs)
  File "c:\users\moris\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 147, in _install_setup_requires
    dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
  File "c:\users\moris\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 673, in fetch_build_eggs
    resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
  File "c:\users\moris\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 764, in resolve
    dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
  File "c:\users\moris\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1049, in best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer)
  File "c:\users\moris\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1061, in obtain
    return installer(requirement)
  File "c:\users\moris\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 732, in fetch_build_egg
    return fetch_build_egg(self, req)
  File "c:\users\moris\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py", line 128, in fetch_build_egg
    raise DistutilsError(str(e)) from e
distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Command '['c:\\users\\moris\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', 'C:\\Users\\Moris\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp4qum52k3', '--quiet', 'numpy>=1.15']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Edit setup.cfg to change the build options; suppress output with --quiet.

BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
  matplotlib: yes [3.3.2]
      python: yes [3.9.0 (tags/v3.9.0:9cf6752, Oct  5 2020, 15:34:40) [MSC
                  v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)]]
    platform: yes [win32]
 sample_data: yes [installing]
       tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]
      macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]

----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try and upgrade your setup tools `pip install --upgrade setuptools` and then install the matplotlib. If that doesn't work I would recommend you to  use a virtual environment like `pyenv` or `conda`

Comment: I have tried that with no success. I'll keep virtual environments as a backup plan but would rather figure out what is wrong with this. Thanks though

Comment: what python version are you using?

Comment: The python version is 3.9.0

Comment: try running it at 3.8

Comment: I got an error as

     error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/ So I downloaded and insallted it but it didn't work for Python 3.9.4

Answer (score -3):

You can also type: `pip --upgrade pip` after having installed Python 3.x and add it to `PATH`.

Comment: No such an option called pip --upgrade pip